# How to get byte array from a bulkTransfer

Tags: java, android, serial-port, usbserial

We'd just programmed our controller to send a 16 bytes message constantly thru the USB port.

After a successful *bulkTransfer*, I'm receiving the 16 bytes.

```
public int bulkTransfer (UsbEndpoint endpoint, byte[] buffer, int offset, int length, int timeout)
```

Now, how can I make the message readable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read the byte array as an object:

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));

Object  obj = in.readObject();